# Cannot use Apache Commons-IO in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm writing a CLI application, using the default template from IntelliJ IDEA.

I installed [commons-io 2.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.8.0), by searching for `commons-io` in the "From Maven" box.

[image]

However, IntelliJ can't find it. For example, I was looking for `CountingInputStream`, which can be imported by:

```kotlin
import org.apache.commons.io.input.CountingInputStream
```

But the import fails at `.io`.

Comment: Since this is already a Gradle-based project, why not use Gradle?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was skimming the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html) and thought it would automagically add `implementation()`. Really rookie mistake on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project is seem to be a Gradle one. Gradle based projects can't add Maven depedencies to their libraries.

Consider adding your library to Gradle build script.

If you use Groovy DSL, add to your build-script the following code (or combine with existing scopes):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0'
}
```

If you use Kotlin DSL, add to your build-script the following code (or combine with existing scopes):

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0")
}
```